# .Net VB email form sending twice for some reason

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, email

My email contact form (for some unknown reason) sends twice, sometimes even three times although this is rare.

**Here's my VB:**

```
<% @Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>

<script language="vb" runat="server">

Sub btnSendFeedback_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

 Dim objMM as New MailMessage()
 objMM.To = "info@emailaddress.com"
 objMM.From = txtEmail.Text
'objMM.Cc = "someone@someaddress.com"
'objMM.Bcc = "someone@someaddress.com"
 objMM.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
 objMM.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
 objMM.Subject = "Scotts Holiday Village"
 objMM.Body = "Hello. At " + DateTime.Now + " an initial enquiry " & _
           "was made " & _
            "by a: " & txtTitle.Text & " " & txtFName.Text & " " & txtLName.Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _               
         ""& txtAdOne.Text & vbCrLf &  _
           txtAdTwo.Text & vbCrLf &  _
           txtAdThree.Text & vbCrLf &  _
          ""& txtCity.Text & vbCrLf &  _
          ""& txtPostCode.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Phone number: " & vbCrLf & txtPhone.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Email address: " & vbCrLf & txtEmail.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "When are you looking to buy?: " & vbCrLf & txtWhenBuy.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Estimated budget: "  & vbCrLf & txtEstBudget.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "What's given you the idea of buying?: " & vbCrLf &txtIdea.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Message: " & vbCrLf &txtMsg.Text & vbCrLf 

   SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.1and1.com"
   SmtpMail.Send(objMM)
   panelSendEmail.Visible = false
   panelMailSent.Visible = true
 End Sub

 </script>
```

**The panelMailSent redirect to a thank you, confirmation page  may have something to do with it, I'm not sure:**

```
<asp:panel id="panelMailSent" runat="server" Visible="False">

<% Response.Redirect("/thankyou/message-sent.aspx") %>

</asp:panel>
```

**The submit button:**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSendFeedback" Text="Send my form"
              OnClick="btnSendFeedback_Click" />
```

**The form method:**

```
<form method="post" id="genericForm" action="default.aspx" name="installer" onsubmit="showHide(); return false;">
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Does it always send twice? Could somebody be pressing the button more than once?

Comment: Hi @David_001 - It is possible, but hopefully they'll go to the confirmation page sharpish. Is there a way I could 'disable' it, second time round (if pressed)?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this method, check call stack on both calls

Comment: Hi @ArsenMkrtchyan, would you mind explaining a little bit more what you mean, I'm relatively new to .Net :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of your page (with the submit button on it), the following javascript might help.  This will prevent double-clicks by disabling the control:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(DoubleClickHandler);
    function DoubleClickHandler(sender, args) 
    { 
        var c = args.get_postBackElement(); 
        c.disabled = true; 
    }
</script>
```

There are lots of other approaches; checking on the server side is safest, but more complex to implement in asp.net. A different approach sometimes used is to not prevent the double submit, but rather store these email requests (in a db, for example), then a task would send all the emails every 5 minutes (say), removing duplicates at the point.